# Mutually exclusive events-Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that A & b are mutually exclusive events. Then P(A)=.3 and P(B)=.5. What is the probability that either A or B occurs? A occurs but b doesn't. Both A and B occur.

1) Since the are mutually exclusive:

$P(A \cup B)= P(A)+P(B)=.3+.5=.8$

2) $A$ occurs $but$ B does not:
$.3$

3) Both $A$ and $B$ occur:

Since they are mutually exclusive:

$P(A \cap B)= 0$ or the empty set

Are these correct

Comment: I assume your question is to check your answers ... You may want to re-evaluate number 2

Comment: Looks good now!

Comment: Note, "*$P(A\cap B)=0$ or the emptyset*"  What is true is that $Pr(A\cap B)=0$ and that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  It is not true that $Pr(A\cap B)$ is the emptyset just as it is not true that $A\cap B=0$.  The one is a set, the other is a number.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about 2)

We always have:

$P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A \cap B^C)$

but now that $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, we have $P(A\cap B)=0$

thus: $P(A\cap B^C)=P(A)$

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact same problem on one of my homework assignments from the Introduction to Probability textbook by Charles M. Grinstead. To guide you in the right direction for part $2$), consider Corollary $2.1$ from his textbook:
For any two events $A$ and $B$ (mutually exclusive in your case), we have
$$P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A\cap B^c)$$ If you want to read more, turn to page $32$ on the following link for the book.
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf